# c++ - How to convert char * buffer to unsigned short int * bufferSh

Tags: c++

How to convert char *buffer to unsigned short int* newBuffer?
Below is my code:

Also, in the resulting newbuffer, how to get the size.
I am reading an Image file in char *buffer and for further processing, I want to convert this char* to unsigned short int *.
Please somebody help me to solve this

```
FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
char * buffer;
size_t result;
pFile = fopen ( "d:\\IMG1" , "rb" );
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}
// obtain file size:
fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = ftell (pFile);
rewind (pFile);
// allocate memory to contain the whole file:
buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}
// copy the file into the buffer:
result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
/* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */
// terminate
fclose (pFile);

unsigned short int *shBuffer = (unsigned short int *)buffer;
int jp2shortsize = sizeof(*shBuffer); 
free (buffer);
```

Comment: that looks more like C code, are you sure you want C++ answer?

Comment: What is the specific problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `reinterpret_cast` in C++ to do the pointer conversions:

```
unsigned short int* ptrA = reinterpret_cast<unsigned short int*>(ptrB);
```

For the size, you have already obtained it, so you'll just need to normalise for the size of the type you are converting to:

```
int jp2shortsize = lSize * sizeof(char) / sizeof(unsigned short int);
```

Comment: If you found the answer helpful you can upvote and/or accept it. Read more at: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . Cheers!

Comment: how to get the size of the buffer from an pointer array?
suppose I have the following array:
unsigned short int* ptrA // Some value.
int size = sizeof(ptrA);

Comment: You cannot get size of buffer from pointer to array (unless you heavily abuse it). You have to keep length alongside with the buffer, use some constant or switch to std::vector class in C++ (or similar).

Answer (score 0):

`fread` function does not need char buffer, it accepts `void *`, so you do not need to cast:

```
size_t const jp2shortsize = lSize / sizeof(unsigned short int);
unsigned short int * shBuffer = (unsigned short int *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned short int) * jp2shortsize);
result = fread(shBuffer, sizeof(unsigned short int), jp2shortsize, pFile); // mind endianess here
```

Comment: Thank you for the speedy useful response.